# What is the difference between 'Save as' and 'Save copy'?

Tags: blend-files, file-browser

When I want to save a copy of my blend file, I know two options:

- File > Save as
- File > Save copy

What is the difference of the two?

And after I press them I see the same result, except difference of 'Save Copy' being checked:

[image]
[image]

When I point my mouse on it it says for both:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess those descriptions are the same because it's the same operator just with another parameter?

Comment: The only real difference is which file you continue working in

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Save As* will save the current file as a new file, and you will continue working in that new file.

*Save A Copy* will save an exact copy of the file with the entered name, and you will continue working in the file you had open before the operation, leaving the copy exactly the same.